# mysql sum() group by

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables here linked by task_id

This is my mysql query,

```
SELECT sum(l.hours)
       ,l.type 
FROM task_details as st 
LEFT JOIN log as l 
ON l.task_id = st.task_id 
WHERE st.task_id IN (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY l.type,st.task_id with roll up
```

What I want is to first find the sum grouped on l.type and then on task_id.
But it is showing me the complete sum without grouping

Comment: You have asked 8 questions and accepted 0 answers, maybe people will be more likely to answer your question if you accept some of those answers that helped you in the past.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just accepted a few answers that were helpful. I always thought it was connected to reputation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WITH ROLLUP` seems to be the problem here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html